# Best practices for ReactiveCocoa with CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, reactive-cocoa

So I've been building an app which works heavily on a custom API, I've built all of the core data models in my app based after the returned Models from the API, some of the features change very regularly based on user interaction and I've been trying to find a way to use ReactiveCocoa with Core data to efficiently stream changes from entities to my views in table cells and so fourth. I have all of my models being mapped regularly from JSON and updating, the only thing I can't work out is what's the best way to use reactive cocoa with core data.

Hopefully someone can help me